# View Pager(Handling Event Listener)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, layout-inflater

I created a Image Slider using View Pager.
I Tried using setOnPageChangeListener but It only triggered when
the user change the page of the viewpager.
What I'm doing(still no luck) is when the user tap on the screen
Another layout will appear.
But Im stuck to triggering the TAP event.

Here's my codes.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.thesis.juandirection.juandirectionfinale.R;
import uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher;

public class viewInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;
    PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_info);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable.bsu, R.drawable.gameover2};
        private Context context;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return image_resources.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return (view == (LinearLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, (ViewGroup) container, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
            ((ViewGroup) container).addView(item_view);

            mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
            mAttacher.update();
            return item_view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
        }
    }

}
```

And the activit's XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pls"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.thesis.juandirection.juandirectionfinale.viewInfos.viewInfo">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the XML layout that will be infalted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#000"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

What I doing is when the user Tap on the Image.
Infos of the image will show on the Same Screen.(Like Facebook viewing photo)

Comment: set `OnClickListener` to the image, and show what you want to show `onClick`

Comment: I've done it but it's not working..